# Use Galaxy Note as digitiser tablet for PC

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, stylus, drawing

So the Samsung Galaxy Note has a stylus and the screen is supposedly a Wacom digitising tablet with 128 levels of pressure sensitivity. Has anyone tried to make it work as a Wacom tablet for a desktop? I'd even be interested in kludge solutions (eg, you draw a shape, it transfers it over wifi, and an app on your PC stores it in the clipboard, so you can just paste it somewhere).

Answer (score 5):

[Unified Remote](http://www.unifiedremote.com/) could satisfy your desire in another way. It can make your Note run as a touch pad and as soon as you have a stylus pen you can open Photoshop on your PC and start painting in it with your stylus.

Unified remote has a free and a full version.

Comment: Interesting. I'd like to try it but it requires .NET 4.0, so I'll think about it for a bit. Something that works with OSX would actually be really useful. (I have an XP desktop, and a Mackbook Pro. Also an XP netbook so maybe I'll try it on that...).

Answer (score 2):

[Use Galaxy Note as digitizer or graphics tablet for PC](http://www.piip.lv/galaxy_note_digitizer_graphics_tablet_for_pc.html) (small project of mine) - maybe this could be relevant, but not exactly what you are looking for. But I found this post based on my search query, so maybe it could be interesting to someone else.

Comment: Answers that consist solely of links are really not answers. What's at the other end of that link? What happens if it goes dead? Please summarize the content here (and provide a link to the source) so that the answer can stand alone.

Comment: Basically this is link to my project that could be relevant to the question, link contains solution (demo video and download), should I better copy paste entire content of that page? :) (But ok fare enough, i made some edits)

Comment: Interesting - I can't try it yet as I don't have ICS. How come you need to "emulate" pressure? Is there no way to access that information directly?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [S-Tablet app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ssm.spen).

Comment: And where might one get this app? How is it used?

Comment: Thanks - pity the English is so poor. Also seems to only apply to Photoshop?