# Using Galaxy Note 2 and stylus to draw in Photochop CS6 on Computer

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2, stylus, drawing

Is there a specific and ultimate complete working application that I could use to draw with my stylus on the Galaxy Note 2 in Photoshop CS6 on my computer? IDK if that makes sense, but what I am trying to do is to use my Note 2 as a tablet to draw with instead of using the mouse on the computer. Please Help!!!

Comment: See this previous question that seems to cover the same ground as yours: [Use an android tablet as a wacom drawing tablet for a PC?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40934/)

Comment: Or [Use Galaxy Note as digitiser tablet for PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19451/)